# Jersey xml annotation for enums

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jersey

I am using web services to return the data to client.Now I have the enum in my code which I want to convert and return it back to the client in json format.
I have googled it , but was not able to find the great solution.

Update : No chance to downvote ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post some code to show a simple example of what you have tried?
This may help. The docs have a few examples. 
http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html